# Draw graph in Latex

Tags: graphics, flow-charts

How to do draw two graphs in one line like this in Latex

[image]

---

one more how about this graphs

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far and what the concrete problems are you are facing. There are several nice examples on this site and on the internet that show how the above can basically be drawn. Also, clarify: Do you need help with the graphs or with the alignment of the figures or with something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is not hard to do once you know how to use Ti*k*Z, but one must admit that the manual, while being incredibly detailed, is not necessarily a good resource to quickly start learning if you are inexperienced with the package.

Anyway here's a simple example that reproduces your first graph (although without the misalignment of the triangles). Since the code is rather self-explanatory, I think it should be enough for you to get started on the other ones.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=2cm,
    y=2cm,
    triangle/.style={
        draw,
        fill=gray!50,
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
        shape border rotate=90
    }
]
    \node at (-.5,0) {\(W_v\)};
    \node at (-.5,1) {\(W_u\)};
    \draw (0,0) node[triangle] {} 
        -- (1,0) node[triangle, label={above left:\(S_{j-1}\)}] {}
        -- (2,1) node[triangle, label={above left:\(S_j\)}] {}
        -- (3,0) node[triangle, label={left:\(S_{j+1}\)}] {}
        -- (4,0) node[triangle] {};
    \draw (0,1) node[triangle] {}
        -- (1,1) node[triangle, label={above left:\(S_{i-1}\)}] {}
        -- (2,0) node[triangle, label={left:\(S_i\)}] {}
        -- (3,1) node[triangle, label={above left:\(S_{i+1}\)}] {}
        -- (4,1) node[triangle] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```